# Ordinal number of the smallest number without array

Tags: c, numbers, minimum

I need help solving this problem, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

The task is:
Write a program that loads n numbers and then prints the smallest as well as its ordinal number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int n,d,m,min=1;
   printf("Enter as many numbers as you want:");
   scanf("%d",&n);

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&m);
    if (i == 1)
    {
        min = m;

    }
    else if (m < min)
        min = m;
}

printf("Min is: %d",min);

}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think they mean the index? (`i` in this case)

Comment: Yes, I think that's what they meant

Comment: `i` corresponding to the minimal number is the "ordinal number". So save it and print.

Comment: BTW, you are initializing `min` to `1`, this is not correct. If you input `2,3,4` for example, it will output `1`.

Comment: I remade it ! :)